# Set Application Name in  MSBuild  Parameters

Tags: command-line, msbuild, web-deployment

I am deploying my web application from command line using this

> msbuild WebApplication1.csproj /t:Package /p:configuration=release

It works fine, but the application deployed with the same name that is using in project settings page.

I want to set the name of deployed application using same command line.
Is there any parameter in msbuild to do so or any other approach.

Thanks

Comment: Can you be more specific about the "name that is using in project settings page"? A Screenshot would help.

Comment: do you mean the assembly name? or the web application name?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You should try this

> msbuild WebApplication1.csproj /t:Package /p:configuration=release;**DeployIISAppPath**="what_ever_name_you_want"

You could get more about these keywords in your project file(.csproj), open it in notepad and search for the default name that is setted by VS. and use that parameter in your command line.

Hope this helps.

Comment: As for now, there's no way to set DeployIISAppPath for asp.net mvc apps in visual studio. This build option works great!

Answer (score 0):

[MS Build Command line parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164311.aspx) : it doesn't look like you can do it from the command line.

But you can do it in your config file - [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171481%28v=vs.80%29) using a property group

```
 <PropertyGroup>
     <appname>NewApplicationName</appname>
 </PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: No, it still sets the same namne that is mentioned in the project properties Package/Publish Web page

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell exactly what setting it is in the property pages that you are talking about however the syntax will be something like this:

> msbuild WebApplication1.csproj /t:Package /p:configuration=release **/p:appname=Test**

Comment: No, it still sets the same namne that is mentioned in the project properties Package/Publish Web page