# How to set publishName/AssemblyName in msbuild command line parameters?

Tags: c#, msbuild

There are two names for the application that you are publishing, the productName and the publishName (publishName/AssemblyName I think they are the same). Both of which you can specify in your .csproj file.

I want to set both of these without changing the .csproj file using MSBuild's command line parameters. So far I have used [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165431.aspx) page from msdn and figured out how to change the product name.

```
MSBuild.exe /t:Build /p:ProductName=$productName.
```

How can I change the publishName in a similar fashion?

When I say publishName I mean the file that gets created with the .application extension. Anyone know what property I need for this - /p:*?

I have also checked out a [Stack Overflow page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10613725/set-application-name-in-msbuild-parameters) and tried all of the suggestions there but they didn't work.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To solve this, I added my own variable in the .csproj file to control the name of the .exe (without affecting the name of the subproject builds):

```
<!-- Make the assembly name configurable -->
<AssemblyName Condition=" '$(MSBuildAssemblyName)' == '' ">MyDefaultAssemblyName</AssemblyName>
<AssemblyName Condition=" '$(MSBuildAssemblyName)' != '' ">$(MSBuildAssemblyName)</AssemblyName>
```

if MSBuildAssemblyName is not specified on the command line, it uses the default name (MyDefaultAssemblyName).

On the command line, invoke it like this:
msbuild ... /p:MSBuildAssemblyName=MyOverriddenName ...

Comment: I can't guarantee that this is the right answer as it was published so long after the original question and I no longer work in C#, but it looks right, so I will mark it as the answer

Comment: Still working for me!

Answer (score 3):

Don't include the quotation marks!

```
MSBuild.exe /t:Build /p:ProductName=$productName;AssemblyName=yourNameHere
```

Also, this won't work if you have another project in the same solution - both will get the same assembly name!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
MSBuild.exe /t:Build /p:ProductName=$productName;AssemblyName="yourNameHere"
```

This was taken from the [MSBuild Command-Line Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms164311.aspx).

Comment: That prevented me from being able to publish

Comment: I got a lot of these (this works when I don't use that assembly name parameter you suggested, which btw I looked at that link and I don't see what you are talking about it doesn't seem to list that as a valid parameter):
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(4264,5): error MSB3073: The command "xcopy *.dll <path to bin folder> /kqry" exited with code 4. [*.csproj]